# correct placement of [today]

Tags: placement

I have made up the sentences today.

(1a) I used the coupon that you gave me **today**.

(1b) I used the coupon **today** that you gave me.

What I mean is you gave me a coupon before. I used it today.

What is the correct position of "today"? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you say you got the coupon today and used it today, 1a covers that. You could not have gotten it yesterday, as you both know. You could not have used it tomorrow, as you both know.

Answer (score 2):

They're both acceptable, but the first could be ambiguous. Yes, "today' is closest to "you gave me," but in colloquial usage it *could* be meant as either:

```
I used the coupon today, that you previously gave me.
```

or

```
I used the coupon which you gave me today.
```

The second is *not* ambiguous, clearly stating that the *coupon* was used today, and that coupon was given *sometime* in the past.

Answer (score 0):

1 is correct but still ambiguous, it's good enough if both parties know which coupon was being talked about, such as when only one coupon was given, and no other coupons were given for extended periods of time before, thus isolating the possibility of which coupon it is

2 is plain unnatural